# How to install MS Core Fonts without my desktop switching to them?

Tags: fonts

I need MS Core fonts to use them with XeLaTeX. I do NOT want them anywhere else.

I tried two ways to get these fonts:

- `fetchmsttfonts` RPM packet
- `msttcore-fonts-installer` from http://mscorefonts2.sourceforge.net (because fetchmsttfonts was not available)

AFAIK both do the same: download MS's *.exe files, extract them to get *.ttf, and install those *.ttf system wide. After that, XeLaTeX works, so that's fine.

However, for some reason these new fonts *instantly* infect my desktop. Before the installation process is even finished, all my Firefox/Leafpad/Terminal fonts are switched to the freshly downloaded ones.

I find this utterly baffling. Why in the world *installing* a font *automatically* switches *the whole system* to it? Is there a way to just install the fonts and keep the desktop untouched?

My OS is OpenSuSE 13.2/42.1 (on different machines), DE is XFCE.

Comment: I have seen this problem only in Firefox and that is a problem originated from most internet sites, that explicitly ask for microsoft named fonts, like Arial and Times New Roman. So when they become available Firefox has no other choice than using them.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re going to use TTF fonts in a LaTeX document anyway, the best solution is probably to use LuaLaTeX, where you can use TTF fonts directly. No installation necessary, just put them into a “fonts” directory next to your tex sources and use the fontspec package to load them, e.g.:

```
% set and load fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
Ligatures = TeX,
ExternalLocation,
Path = {./fonts/},
Extension = {.otf},
UprightFont = {*Regular},
BoldFont = {*Bold},
ItalicFont = {*Italic},
BoldItalicFont = {*BoldItalic}]{Charter}
\setsansfont[
Ligatures = TeX,
Scale = MatchLowercase,
ExternalLocation,
Path = {./fonts/},
Extension = {.ttf},
UprightFont = {*},
BoldFont = {*-Bold},
ItalicFont = {*-Oblique},
BoldItalicFont = {*-BoldOblique}]{Helvetica}
\setmonofont[
Ligatures = TeX,
Scale = MatchLowercase]{Latin Modern Mono}
```